# Facebook comments plugin in canvas app: Comment at visitor's wall looks ugly

Tags: facebook, comments, facebook-canvas

i want to place a comment box at the bottom of a page tab/canvas page so that visitors can post comments that will be shown on that page and - if the user checks the checkbox - at the visitor's wall. I do this with the comments plugin

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="[link to real url of this page]" data-num-posts="2" data-width="520"></div>
```

The comment looks nice in the comments box. The comment looks ugly at the visitor's wall. The comment at the visitor's wall seems to gather the meta tag information of the comments box page. I have customized the meta tags according to http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/ and tested the setting by the facebook linter at http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug with a good result. Now the comment at the visitor's wall looks fine with some small problems:

1. the comment does not link to the facebook-url (http://www.facebook.com/pages/..) but to the real url of the page (http://www.somewhere.com/page-with-comments.php) which is not desired
2. the comment contains a link pointing to the real url, which is not desired at all

For (2) i had a similiar problem when generating a post at the visitor's wall by

```
FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { picture: pic, caption: ' ', description: desc, link: link }, function(response) {});
```

but then the link could be avoided by setting a caption attribute of one empty space. Unfortunately this attribute (og:caption) seems not be liked by the facebook linter. For (1) i have no idea how to solve the problem as the linter does not like any facebook-urls in the meta tag og:url, which on the other hand is responsable for the link target of the comment at the visitor's wall. This is not good.

Long message short, how do you implement the comments plugin on a page tab/canvas page with a nice look of the comment at the visitor's wall and a link at the comment to the page tab/canvas page.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

In order to obtain what you are looking for, you have to add the Open Graph meta tags to the page that you're using as href in the fb-comments div.

The description of the supported tags is here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/

You can check what the facebook scraper sees when reading your page by using the debugger tool here:
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug